# DDD Edit many properties in one transaction

Tags: user-interface, domain-driven-design

We start building the software by DDD. Trying to identify ReachDomain. But the problem is that our Domain experts want a Crud based UI. When I ask them why do you need to update many props in one transaction, they answer: "It could be that initially I din't enter them correctly". That's funny, but what should I answer? How can I persuade them to switch to Task Based UI and do Rich Domain?

Answer (score 0):

In case the domain is simple, with little or no behavior, you may stick with the CRUD based entities. In this case, there are a lot of tools to manage the UI generation and persistence. Most of the work is already done by them so you can produce rapidly the software.

If, however, the domain is complex and you need to use DDD, you may have a CRUD based UI but a DDD domain layer. You have to map the UI modifications to domain commands.

For example, if you have a checkbox named `accoundIsActive`, then, after the user press the Submit button, you check the value of the checkbox and send `ActivateAccount` or `DeactivateAccount` command.

Regarding the execution of multiple commands in one transaction, you could create a bulk modification command that is composed of individual commands; in this way the Aggregate will execute the bulk command in one transaction.

Comment: Could it be that such mapping is very complex and impossible to do? I think it could be very complex. Your example is very simple.

Comment: @DmitriBodiu yes, it can be very complex; you have to decide for yourself; one alternative (if the first doesn't work) is that the Aggregate is receiving CRUD commands but it's yielding DDD events, probably by observing what changed using it's internal private state.

Answer (score 0):

"Amend entity" is a perfectly valid task in a task-based UI.

Task-based UI `≠` update one property at a time.

Besides, just because *some* tasks look like CRUD doesn't mean there aren't other tasks that require a rich domain model. CRUDness isn't a contagious disease ;)

Comment: ""Amend entity" is a perfectly valid task in a task-based UI." - yes. But NOT changing 5 properties at once, unless all 5 properties are related somehow, i.e Address contains Street, apt. number, zipCode, City, Country.

Comment: @DimitriBodiu Why?

Comment: Task based UI means you navigate user to perform a task related to business. Your business will never have a usecase SAying Update(). I will be RelocateUserToANewAddressCommand and your UI should send that command to Backend. https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/

Comment: Task-based UI is guidelines, not dogma. If some part of the business is CRUDish in nature, so be it. Definitely try hard to come up with smaller, more focused tasks, but if it's not possible, don't shoehorn a legit Update/Adjust/Amend case into contrived, unnatural sub-tasks.

Comment: Exactly. If there is no any business behaviour, CrudBased UI should be applied. My analysts want behaviour, and at the same time modification of multiple fields on UI, so the question is how to persuade them that updating/adjusting multiple fields is nonsense.

Comment: Your analysts may be right. There can be CRUD-like behaviors **and** rich behaviors **on the same entity/UI**. Adjusting multiple fields is not nonsense, it can be legit. You have to embrace it when it is needed. It doesn't mean you let go of rich domain tasks on that entity.